# How to decide probability of Erdos renyi random graph model

Tags: r, graph-theory

I am understanding the logic behind erdos ranyi's random graph model.I am generating this random graph using R studio. This model has two subparts one is G(n,p) in which, n = total number of nodes and p = probability that any two nodes share an edge. We will have to give probability as an input to pass. Suppose if i take a random experiment of coin flipping then the if there is heads i will connect two nodes and if there is tails i will not connect two nodes that would be having probability 0.5. I am not getting that when suppose i will provide probability p = 0.3 and number of nodes are 5 then how the nodes will get connected based on the 0.3 probability. My r script is as follows.

```
library(igraph)
g10 <- erdos.renyi.game(5,0.3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 5 nodes, then you have 5*4/2 = 10 possible edges in an undirected graph. If each edge has existence with probability 0.3, then the distribution of the number of edges over multiple instances of those graphs is Binomial with probability 0.3 and size 10.

Let's experiment. Generate 1000 graphs and tabulate the number of nodes:

```
> g3_edges = table(replicate(1000,length(E(erdos.renyi.game(5,.3)))))
> g3_edges

  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
 34 132 230 266 194 100  31  12   1
```

The theoretical distribution of 0 to 8 edges from 10 with p=0.3 is given by `dbinom`, and I'll multiply by my 1000 simulation count and take integers for comparison with my simulation table:

```
> p3_edges = as.integer(dbinom(0:8, size=10, p=0.3)*1000)
> p3_edges
[1]  28 121 233 266 200 102  36   9   1
```

Which looks pretty close, and probably within the random sampling variation. Also we didn't generate any graphs with 9 or 10 edges, and the theoretical distribution is already down to 1 at 8 edges, so that's not surprising either.

```
> cbind(g3_edges, p3_edges)
  g3_edges p3_edges
0       34       28
1      132      121
2      230      233
3      266      266
4      194      200
5      100      102
6       31       36
7       12        9
8        1        1
```

Repeat with p=0.5 if you want. In this case I got graphs with up to 9 edges:

```
> g5_edges = table(replicate(1000,length(E(erdos.renyi.game(5,.5)))))
> p5_edges = as.integer(dbinom(0:9, size=10, p=0.5)*1000)
> cbind(g5_edges, p5_edges)
  g5_edges p5_edges
0        2        0
1       14        9
2       53       43
3      102      117
4      216      205
5      266      246
6      199      205
7       91      117
8       39       43
9       18        9
```

So where's your problem?

Comment: my confusion is when we choose probability value as 0.3 and we place 5 nodes in a space then if i pick suppose 4th node from the graph then probability of connecting 4th node to any other node is 0.3. What does that mean when to connect 4th node with any other node and when not with 0.3 probability.

Comment: Do you not understand what probability is or what a graph is?

Comment: I do understand what a graph is and also what is probability.

Comment: So what don't you understand about the construction of a graph via this method? Take the 5 nodes, then the full graph has 10 edges. Keep each of those edges with probability 0.3, leaving somewhere between 0 and 10 edges, with an average of 3 edges.

Comment: Ok that means that in a graph on an average it would be having maximum 3 edges. That means each edge is connected with pair of vertices having probability 0.3. And which of the three edges the random graph will have that depend on a random experiment we do. Suppose we flip a coin so either it would be having 3 heads that means 3 edges or 2,1,0 and 2,1,0 edges respectively.

Comment: Each of the ten possible edges between all pairs of nodes exists with probability 0.3. Conditional on node i having N edges, the probability of an edge existing to node j is N/5 in this case.

Comment: What N stands for..??

Comment: N is however many edges a given node has. If node A has 2 edges, then it has an equal probability of connecting to any two other nodes. It could be B,C or B,D or B,E, or C,D or C,E or D,E, and each of those six pairs with equal probability of 1/6.